# Having dns_probe_finished_domainnx regularly on a domain

Tags: heroku, dns, ovh

I get something weird. With a firend of mine, we've created this website : https://www.matosmaison.fr . On some computers with different ISP, a lot of times, the website and the name resolution is done well.

But sometimes, crawling tools and by ourselves, we meet the error dns_probe_finished_domainnx. Do you have any idea about what happens ?

On DownForEveryOneOrJustMe, it says it's ok, but we can reproduce it easily.
http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/matosmaison.fr

Here is our DNS mapping :

```
matosmaison.fr. 0       NS      dns200.anycast.me.      
matosmaison.fr. 0       NS      ns200.anycast.me.       
matosmaison.fr. 0       MX      1 redirect.ovh.net.     
matosmaison.fr. 0       CNAME   www.matosmaison.fr.herokudns.com.       
www.matosmaison.fr. 0   CNAME   www.matosmaison.fr.herokudns.com.
```

Thanks in advance for all suggestions and help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the "solution". OVH is currently working on a maintenance problem on their servers. So it's "normal".

Here I can track the evolution of maintenance : http://travaux.ovh.net/?do=details&id=21665